# Openrefine - Split Columns by using space

Tags: openrefine

I am new to OpenRefine, and got data like this:

Studies in Comparative International Development 960 1.087 1.451 A-/B+ 3-star

I would like to split by using the space from reverse order (counting from the end).  How I should express this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following grel expression to split on space and select the last element of the array  `value.split(' ')[-1]`

You can use -2 and so on to move backward in the array.

Comment: Thanks!  I got it.  May I ask one more advice. If I want to retain all value prior to the last space, what can I do?

Comment: You can combine the previous expression with the replace function  to replace the last event of the array by nothing. In your case you will use `value.replace(value.split(' ')[-1],'')`